# Python Request Find String

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I'am tring something with python and request module. But I couldn't. What is the problem. I need to find Sold Out but in the page.

```
import requests
url = "https://wunder.com.tr/sneaker/adidas-sneaker/yeezy-boost-700-v3-H67799? 
gclid=CjwKCAjwnIr1BRAWEiwA6GpwNSZ5WT1GuFdTO1nXkwYLl__RXY0PZ6Atez4_ZYB- 
DSNEbzz3Z3swGRoCkAsQAvD_BwE"
req = requests.get(url)
gelen = req.content
ss = "Sold Out"
if ss in gelen:
print ("yok")
else:
print ("var")
```

Comment: What is the actual result, and what's the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the module **re** to find your text:

```
import requests
import re
url = "https://wunder.com.tr/sneaker/adidas-sneaker/yeezy-boost-700-v3-H67799? 
gclid=CjwKCAjwnIr1BRAWEiwA6GpwNSZ5WT1GuFdTO1nXkwYLl__RXY0PZ6Atez4_ZYB- 
DSNEbzz3Z3swGRoCkAsQAvD_BwE"
req = requests.get(url)
if re.search('(?i)sold out',req.text):
    print('yok')
else:
    print('var')
```

'(?i)sold out' will makes the sold out string search case insensitive so it will find all instances of sold out. Also, you did not indent the if else outputs properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it works very well. But again i want to ask a question. If I want to search a string like a=="adsad" not sold out. How can it possible